# Pytorch - add rows of a 2D tensor element-wise

Tags: addition, pytorch

I have the following tensor :

```
ts = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,6,7],[8,9,10]])
> tensor([[ 1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  6,  7],
    [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

I am looking for a pytorch generic operation that adds all rows element-wise like that:

```
ts2 = ts[0]+ts[1]+ts[2]
print(ts2)
> tensor([13, 17, 20])
```

In reality, the number of rows corresponds to the batch size that vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum over an axis/dimension like so:

```
torch.sum(ts, dim=0)
```

Comment: Thanks feliks. That's exactly what I wanted